# How to implement a toolbar for a TextField in a new view linked to a NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar

END GOAL: Have a toolbar pop up on top of the keypad to finish inputting number.

I am running into an issue where in my main view I have a NavigationView to different "scenes/views" and in one of the views I have a text input. I tried adding a toolbar but the toolbar fails to be added properly because of the underlying NavigationView I believe. I have provided a visual example of the error at the end.

Here is the simplified code for the Textfield:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Quantity", value: $quantity, format: .number)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Done") {
                        isEditing = false
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Here is the MainView code:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            // other nav links here as well
            NavigationLink(destination: MarketView()) {
                Image(systemName: "cart.fill")
                Text("Market")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The user goes from the main view into the market view and then when they click to adjust the quantity the input field pops up and the toolbar for the info field pops up with an extra Done button.

This is the entire error from the console, where I think it is having issue with the navigation view colliding with the toolbar being on the input.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x2809772a0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x101527930.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2809620d0 H:|-(20)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x1015283b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x101527930 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280960af0 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x1015283b0]-(20)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x101527930 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280976c10 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x2813e9420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UITAMICAdaptorView:0x102918dd0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280976c60 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x2813e9420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UITAMICAdaptorView:0x102919310.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280976cb0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UITAMICAdaptorView:0x102918dd0]-(0)-[UIView:0x102919190]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280976d00 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x102919190]-(0)-[_UITAMICAdaptorView:0x102919310]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280960640 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2813e9420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x1015283b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280961090 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x2813e9420'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x1015283b0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280976d00 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x102919190]-(0)-[_UITAMICAdaptorView:0x102919310]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Here is an example of what it looks like on iOS and iPadOS
[image: iPad version of Error]
[image: iPhone version of Error]